# Star Pattern in C- 2nd half is not printing

Tags: c

I've been trying to print star pattern but it's not working after 
"if(i>4)" as you can see the second image there's a gap in between which implies that the spaces are getting printing or the new line but the star pattern is not getting printed

[image: Star pattern]

```
enter code here

//the first half
int main() {
 int i,j,k,m;
 for (i=1;i<=4;i++) {
     for (j=1;j<=4-i;j++) {
        printf(" ");
     }
     for(k=1;k<=i;k++)
     {
        printf("*");
     }
     printf("\n"); // to print the first half
 }
 //the second half
 if(i>4){
 for(j=1;j<=i-2;j++)
 {
     for (k=1;k<=j;k++) {
        printf(" ");
     }
     for(m=1;m<=4-i;m++)
     {
        printf("*");
     }
     printf("\n");
 }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: The "second half" part isn't within a function. I don't think this will compile, and if it did, it would never execute that part.

Comment: I've written this within the function main but still it is not working

Comment: This is probably a good time to [learn how to debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Using a debugger you can step through your code line by line, seeing exactly what it does while also being able to monitor variables and their values.

Comment: Even some simple [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) should be helpful. When doing that, in the second half pay attention to the loop condition `m<=4-i`. When will that condition be true?

Comment: @EkataBavkar I wrote that before it was edited, the second half was previously outside the function. As it is now, look at that second loop in the second part. You start with `i=5`, but compare m to `4-i`

Comment: _What's the `i` value here in `if(i>4){` ?_ Its `5`. And this `m<=4-i` won't executes as `1<=-1` i.e condition fails, hence doesn't print `*`. work on `m<=4-i` part.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    n = n/2+1;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=n-i;j>=1;j--)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for(int k=1;k<=i;k++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {

        for(int k=1;k<=i;k++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for(int j=n-i;j>=1;j--)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9a9D.png)